# Distinguishing between phone and tablet browsers

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, mobile, webforms

I know this question as been beaten to death, but I don't want anything super complicated here.

We have a companion app with our site that is only compatible with 7 and 10-inch tablets.  We need to only alert users on those devices about our app.  Problem is, I can't go by resolution.  My Galaxy S3 has a 1280 x 720 screen, but is obviously not a tablet.  I also can't for the life of me find out a way to get the **physical** size of the screen.  The only solution I have come up with is detecting whether the device can make calls with `MobileCapabilities.CanInitiateVoiceCall`.  Unfortuantely, by boss isn't happy with that solution.

So...  How can I distinguish between a phone and a tablet in my web app (Server or client side)?

**UPDATE:** So far it seems that the best approach for Android is something from a blog post by the Android team:  *All* Android phones use "Mobile" in the UserAgent string, so checking for "Mobile" **and* "Android" will tell you if it's a phone, while just "Android" should be a tablet.  iOS devices should be just as simple--checking for "iPhone" vs "iPad" seems to have worked so far.

Comment: *“We need to only alert users on those devices about our app”* – Why? If a device has an appropriate resolution to display your content, don’t keep them out. Make your design responsive, and support *any* device.

Comment: If what you really want is to distinguish between a phone and tablet, I think by definition what makes a phone a phone is whether it can make phone calls.  I'm not sure what your ultimate goal is, but the line between tablet/computer/phone is becoming quite fuzzy, and being able to make calls is the only thing that still makes a phone a phone.

Comment: If an android phone and tablet both have a good resolution large enough for your app, what is different between the two devices that you need to make the distinction?  The answer to that should be what you use to determine what you should hinge your decision on.

Comment: @poke: Unfortunately, we didn't write the app, (outsourced) and the app that exists has explicit compatiblity with only 7" and 10" tablets.  If a user on an incompatible device follows the link to our app, they will only get a "your device is incompatible" message on the Play Store.  So basically this is a workaround for bad design.

Comment: Then checking for phone calling ability is probably not a compelte solution.  Some Galaxy 7/10" tablets have a GSM antenna and thus can make phone calls(although IDK what the API would report or if the carriers disable this in their build of the OS): http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_p7100_galaxy_tab_10_1v-3831.php

Comment: Try this project to detect current browser with details : https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little late, but I was looking for the same thing.

[Wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) has wat you want. You can implement it easily and and even have an api you can query.

For ASP.NET application first you must place the one-off initialization.

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
   public const String WurflDataFilePath = "~/App_Data/wurfl.zip";
   private void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var wurflDataFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(WurflDataFilePath);
       var configurer = new InMemoryConfigurer().MainFile(wurflDataFile);
       var manager = WURFLManagerBuilder.Build(configurer);
       HttpContext.Current.Cache[WurflManagerCacheKey] = manager;
   }
}
```

And then use it like this.

```
var device = WURFLManagerBuilder.Instance.GetDeviceForRequest(userAgent);
var isTablet = device.GetCapability("is_tablet");
var isSmartphone = device.GetCapability("is_smartphone");
```

For more info check [ASP.NET implementation](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/dotnet_index.php)

Hope this helps anyone else looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a user agent detection and search for the keywrords, for example, all Non tablet devices have a "Mobile Safari" key words on their user agent.

Comment: Just "Mobile Safari" doesn't work because both phones and tablets (at least for iOS devices have that in their UserAgent.